# IIS CertificateHash is Null when bound to an IP

Tags: powershell, iis

Currently I am unable to get the certificate hash from PowerShell on my IIS server when I have a certificate and an IP bound to the site.

To get this information I'm running the following

```
$Bindings = (Get-ItemProperty -path IIS:\Sites\$Name -Name Bindings).collection | Where-Object {$_.Protocol -like "*http*" -and $_.Protocol -ne $null}
```

When I access $bindings.certificateHash I get nothing.

```
PS C:\> $Bindings = (Get-ItemProperty -path IIS:\Sites\$Name -Name Bindings).collection | Where-Object {$_.Protocol -lik
e "*http*" -and $_.Protocol -ne $null}
PS C:\> $bindings.certificateHash
PS C:\>
```

If I remove the IP address binding I get the certificatehash back.  Any ideas what could be wrong?

---

Computer Information:

- OS: 2008R2
- IIS: 7.5
- PowerShell: 4.0

Comment: did you bind/associate like described here ? http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in

Comment: Looks like I'm using a slight variation of that. You can see the binding code https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/DSC/blob/master/Resources/cWebAdministration/DSCResources/PSHOrg_cWebsite/PSHOrg_cWebsite.psm1#L605

However, I've also manually setup the website through the gui and have still seen the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the binding of the SSL certificate itself.  I had to delete everything and bind it again and the problem went away. Not sure what caused it but its working now.